# How do i specify that i want ruby1.9 in my Rails Projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Simply, how do you specify that you want ruby1.9 for your project ? And how do you check that it is indeed using it ? I have 1.8.7 and 1.9 in my system currently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [RVM](https://rvm.io) you can add `.rvmrc` file in project root directory with content:

```
rvm use 1.9.2-p180
```

After that when you go to a project directory with terminal, rvm will switch to specified ruby automatically:

```
$> cd ~/code/project
Using /home/voldy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180
```